# What do I wait or join on when using channels and threads?

Tags: multithreading, rust

Here's an example but what should I wait on to decide when it is done. Do we have a better way to wait for the channel to be empty and all the threads to have completed? Full example is at http://github.com/posix4e/rust_webcrawl

```
loop {
    let n_active_threads = running_threads.compare_and_swap(0, 0, Ordering::SeqCst);
    match rx.try_recv() {
        Ok(new_site) => {
            let new_site_copy = new_site.clone();
            let tx_copy = tx.clone();
            counter += 1;

            print!("{} ", counter);
            if !found_urls.contains(&new_site) {
                found_urls.insert(new_site);
                running_threads.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
                let my_running_threads = running_threads.clone();
                pool.execute(move || {
                    for new_url in get_websites_helper(new_site_copy) {
                        if new_url.starts_with("http") {
                            tx_copy.send(new_url).unwrap();
                        }
                    }
                    my_running_threads.fetch_sub(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
                });
            }
        }
        Err(TryRecvError::Empty) if n_active_threads == 0 => break,
        Err(TryRecvError::Empty) => {
             writeln!(&mut std::io::stderr(),
                "Channel is empty, but there are {} threads running",
                n_active_threads);
              thread::sleep_ms(10);
        },
        Err(TryRecvError::Disconnected) => unreachable!(),
    }
}
```

Comment: would you mind posting a smaller example? (something that runs in the [PlayPen](play.rust-lang.org) would of course be the most comfortable solution for answerers)

Comment: I have kinda given up on this to work  https://github.com/carllerche/eventual/issues/4

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a very complicated question, one with a great potential for race conditions! As I understand it, you:

1. Have an unbounded queue
2. Have a set of workers that operate on the queue items
3. The workers can put an *unknown* amount of items back into the queue
4. Want to know when everything is "done"

One obvious issue is that it may **never be done**. If every worker puts one item back into the queue, you've got an infinite loop.

That being said, I feel like the solution is to track

1. How many items are queued
2. How many items are in progress

When both of these values are zero, then you are done. Easier said than done...

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize,Ordering};
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel,TryRecvError};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let running_threads = Arc::new(AtomicUsize::new(0));
    let (tx, rx) = channel();

    // We prime the channel with the first bit of work
    tx.send(10).unwrap();

    loop {
        // In an attempt to avoid a race condition, we fetch the
        // active thread count before checking the channel. Otherwise,
        // we might read nothing from the channel, and *then* a thread
        // finishes and added something to the queue.
        let n_active_threads = running_threads.compare_and_swap(0, 0, Ordering::SeqCst);

        match rx.try_recv() {
            Ok(id) => {
                // I lie a bit and increment the counter to start
                // with. If we let the thread increment this, we might
                // read from the channel before the thread ever has a
                // chance to run!
                running_threads.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);

                let my_tx = tx.clone();
                let my_running_threads = running_threads.clone();

                // You could use a threadpool, but I'm spawning
                // threads to only rely on stdlib.
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    println!("Working on {}", id);

                    // Simulate work
                    thread::sleep_ms(100);

                    if id != 0 {
                        my_tx.send(id - 1).unwrap();
                        // Send multiple sometimes
                        if id % 3 == 0 && id > 2 {
                            my_tx.send(id - 2).unwrap();
                        }
                    }

                    my_running_threads.fetch_sub(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
                });
            },
            Err(TryRecvError::Empty) if n_active_threads == 0 => break,
            Err(TryRecvError::Empty) => {
                println!("Channel is empty, but there are {} threads running", n_active_threads);
                // We sleep a bit here, to avoid quickly spinning
                // through an empty channel while the worker threads
                // work.
                thread::sleep_ms(1);
            },
            Err(TryRecvError::Disconnected) => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
}
```

I make no guarantees that this implementation is perfect (I probably *should* guarantee that it's broken, because threading is hard). One big caveat is that I don't intimately know the meanings of all the variants of [`Ordering`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/enum.Ordering.html), so I chose the one that looked to give the strongest guarantees.